# How to rebuild web api project in IIS on local pc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

So i have a project in folder A , its a folder where i'm coding and developing .
And i have folder B , its a folder which i have deployed on my local Windows internet information services

Problem is , when i change any cs file, lets say example.cs copied from folder A to folder B and then when i run my link example/login, it shows me old output
any way you guys rebuild project on internet information services or how it work ?

```
public class OnLoginData
    {
        public IEnumerable<TableDetails> lstTableDetails { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CategoryMenuDetails> lstCategoryMenuDetails { get; set; }
        public int AdminId { get; set; }
        public int SystemId { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you should use the Publish feature, you can't just copy code files. The site is compiled into a dll.

Comment: Why can't you use VS and IIS Express? If running the site directly from VS using IIS Express isn't an option for some reason, then you have to use Publish as stated above.

Comment: @VladStryapko thanks for responding , yes im using VS , the reason im using IIS on local because this is the first time im developing a project on MVC pattern and before making the project live i want to just check if the update files are working on IIS or not. because everytime we have to rebuild the project on VS after changes, so i want to make a practice of same on IIS server level . Could you help me ?

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for responding, i can understand that there is a publish option on VS , but there will be no Visual studio on live server (AWS) , we mostly create a site on IIS using folder .

Comment: Thank you everyone , i got the solution